# Width property not applying to VideoJS play Button

Tags: javascript, css, video.js

I created a video grid in a SP website we have in our company, using the "videojs" plugin for the videos. The problem is that I can't properly resize the Play Button, as the "width" property from the CSS file is not applying to it.

I've tried a few things I read on the forums:
display:block; (also tried flex)
clear: both;
max-width and width combined

But none of them seem to work.

The CSS file I linked my HTML to has the following content:

```
.vjs-big-play-centered .vjs-big-play-button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 3em;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

And the HTML code that displays the videos is:

```
<video id='my-video' class='video-js vjs-big-play-centered' controls preload='auto' width='288' height='216'
  poster='https://comunidad.mercantilandina.com.ar/sites/MesadeAyuda/Descargas/Thumbnail-Instructivos/Celulares/Acceso%20a%20datos%20celular.png' data-setup='{}'>
    <source src='https://comunidad.mercantilandina.com.ar/sites/MesadeAyuda/Videos/Abrir%20carpeta%20en%20outlook.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
    <p class='vjs-no-js'>
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
      <a href='https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/' target='_blank'>supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>
```

The button should be a 50px * 50px square, but instead it's displayed as a rectangle (with the right height).

Comment: where is your `.vjs-big-play-button` class in the code?

Comment: Works here with your exact CSS: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KOVXag

Comment: Hmmm...it works here, when I simplify your CSS, by adjusting the width and height to both being "50px", then I get what you say you want.  (So, you went wrong somewhere, when came up with the values  you show.)

Comment: I found out that the button was being affected by a parent CSS file in the SharePoint enviroment (Input Button "min-width" property).

Comment: That said, tho I get the 50x50 square button you want, there's an unwanted side-effect of the button not disappearing during playing.  So, I question whether altering the std supplied buttons is really worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the button was being affected by a parent CSS file in the SharePoint enviroment (Input Button "min-width" property).
I solved the problem by "overwriting" that CSS property only in that specific page.
Thanks for all the help!